# php mysqli get bool value from db

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve the value of a bool or tinyint. Using the example from php.net. When I run the script I either get "0 results" or "Array", depending if my query has a result.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "testdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT OnOff FROM mission_control limit 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "$row";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

In the command line I can do this...

```
mysql> select * FROM mission_control WHERE id=1;
+----+-------+
| id | OnOff |
+----+-------+
|  1 |     0 |
+----+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I will only ever have 1 ID (i'm considering removing it), but I only care to retrieve the value of "OnOff".

Bonus question How can I assign the result 0 or 1 to a variable that I can do an "IF" statement on?

Comment: `echo $row['OnOff'];` instead of `echo "$row";`

Comment: If you throw away mysqli for PDO you could use `fetchColumn()`.

Comment: you ALREADY can use $row['OnOff'] in an IF statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetch_assoc` returns an array, so `echo "$row"` will simply output "Array".  Instead reference the column name:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['OnOff'];
}
```

Comment: ***Bonus question*** How can I assign the result 0 or 1 to a variable that I can do an "IF" statement on?

Comment: if($row['OnOff'] == 1 || $row['OnOff'] == 0) // do something

Answer (score 3):

@nyitguy, You are asking php to give you back an associative array.

```
$row = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

So you get an array back and that is what you are echoing.

The value you want is `$row['OnOff']`, not `$row`.